# Efficiently updating a table from multiple sources

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm working on improving part of an existing ETL layer in Oracle.

1. A file is loaded in to a temporary table.
2. Many MERGE statement are executed to resolve surrogate keys.
3. Some other business logic is applied (which require those surrogate keys).
4. The results are MERGEd
   in to a table (with both the surrogate keys and the business logic
   results)

It's step 2 that I want to improve, it seems *less than ideal* to do this as several steps.

```
MERGE INTO temp t
USING dimension_1 d1 ON (d1.natural_key = t.d1_natural_key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE t.d1_id = d1.id

MERGE INTO temp t
USING dimension_2 d2 ON (d2.natural_key = t.d2_natural_key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE t.d2_id = d2.id

MERGE INTO temp t
USING dimension_3 d3 ON (d3.natural_key = t.d3_natural_key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE t.d3_id = d3.id
```

If I was writing this in SQL Server I'd do something like the following:

```
UPDATE
    t
SET
    d1_id = COALESCE(d1.id, -1),
    d2_id = COALESCE(d2.id, -1),
    d3_id = COALESCE(d3.id, -1)
FROM
    temp  t
LEFT JOIN
    dimension_1   d1
        ON d1.natural_key = t.d1_natural_key
LEFT JOIN
    dimension_2   d2
        ON d2.natural_key = t.d2_natural_key
LEFT JOIN
    dimension_3   d3
        ON d3.natural_key = t.d3_natural_key
```

For the life of me I can't find what seems like a sensible option in Oracle.  The best I have been able to work out is to use UPDATE *(while everyone around me is screaming that I 'must' use MERGE)* and correlated sub-queries; something like...

```
UPDATE
    temp t
SET
    d1_id = COALESCE((SELECT id FROM dimension_1 d1 WHERE d1.natural_key = t.d1_natural_key), -1),
    d2_id = COALESCE((SELECT id FROM dimension_2 d2 WHERE d2.natural_key = t.d2_natural_key), -1),
    d3_id = COALESCE((SELECT id FROM dimension_3 d3 WHERE d3.natural_key = t.d3_natural_key), -1)
```

Are there any better alternatives?  Or is the correlated sub-query approach actually performant in Oracle?

Comment: Why have you rejected the left-join approach for Oracle? The syntax would be slightly different but the idea would work.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Because I didn't account for the `SET (x, y, z) = (SELECT x, y, z FROM blah)` syntax to make the `UPDATE` work, and because to make the `MERGE` work required the table being updated to join against it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the equivalent of your SQL Server update would be:

```
UPDATE
    temp t1
SET
    (d1_id, d2_id, d3_id) = (
SELECT
    COALESCE(d1.id, -1),
    COALESCE(d2.id, -1),
    COALESCE(d3.id, -1)
FROM
    temp  t2
LEFT JOIN
    dimension_1   d1
        ON d1.natural_key = t2.d1_natural_key
LEFT JOIN
    dimension_2   d2
        ON d2.natural_key = t2.d2_natural_key
LEFT JOIN
    dimension_3   d3
        ON d3.natural_key = t2.d3_natural_key
WHERE
    t2.id = t1.id 
)
```

It's still a correlated update; the joining takes place in the subquery, since Oracle doesn't let you join as part of the update itself. Normally you wouldn't need (or want) to refer to the target outer table again in the subquery, but you need something to outer-join against here.

You can also combine the left-join approach with a merge, putting essentially the same subquery into the `using` clause:

```
MERGE INTO temp t
USING (
  SELECT t.id,
    COALESCE(d1.id, -1) AS d1_id,
    COALESCE(d2.id, -1) AS d2_id,
    COALESCE(d3.id, -1) AS d3_id
  FROM
    temp  t
  LEFT JOIN
    dimension_1   d1
      ON d1.natural_key = t.d1_natural_key
  LEFT JOIN
    dimension_2   d2
      ON d2.natural_key = t.d2_natural_key
  LEFT JOIN
    dimension_3   d3
      ON d3.natural_key = t.d3_natural_key
) d
ON (d.id = t.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  t.d1_id = d.d1_id,
  t.d2_id = d.d2_id,
  t.d3_id = d.d3_id
```

I don't see any real benefit of using merge over update in this case though.

Both will overwrite any existing values in your three ID columns, but it sounds like you are not expecting there to be any.

Comment: Thanks for that, the ability to update a set isn't something I had encountered.  Being that the temp table itself could be quite large (hundred of thousands to low millions) would you expect the self join (`t2.id = t1.id`) to incur a large cost?  In my attempts to get MERGE to work I did end up with what you had, but that self join really did seem an unnecessary cost.

Comment: You're hitting every row in term to update anyway. As it's a temporary table (I assume you mean an actual one, a global temporary table, rather than a permanent table you're creating then dropping) it's all in memory so that cost could be high, but for both. Your three separate merges might be more memory efficient for a GTT; you'd need to experiment, and see what the execution plans look like.

Comment: I at-least now have a few different options and the confirmation that I'm not missing anything blindingly obvious *(except my blind spot for `SET (x,y,z) = `)*, thanks.

Comment: @MatBailie - how are you loading the file into the temporary table? If you're using an external table for that you could do the joins at that point, so the insert into temp has the right IDs in the first place.

Comment: We're very constrained in what we have access to at present, so it's actually horrendous; Prepared statements in the form `INSERT INTO global_temp_table (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` then executing the prepared statement in batches of 50k.  Although choke-worthy, it's not actually the longest running part of the overall task, so it can get some attention another day.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may be more efficient than Alex's answer -- requiring only one access of the `temp` table, instead of two.  On my quick test of a million rows, performance was about the same, but the plan is better since there is no second access of the `temp` table.  It may be worth trying on your data set.

```
UPDATE
 ( SELECT      d1.id s_d1_id,
               d2.id s_d2_id,
               d3.id s_d3_id,
               mt.d1_id,
               mt.d2_id,
               mt.d3_id
        FROM   temp mt
               LEFT JOIN dimension_1 d1 ON d1.natural_key = mt.d1_natural_key
               LEFT JOIN dimension_2 d2 ON d2.natural_key = mt.d2_natural_key
               LEFT JOIN dimension_3 d3 ON d3.natural_key = mt.d3_natural_key )
SET d1_id =    COALESCE (s_d1_id, -1), d2_id = COALESCE (s_d2_id, -1), d3_id = COALESCE (s_d3_id, -1);
```

The caveat is, you need `UNIQUE` constraints on the `natural_key` columns in each dimension table.  With these constraints, Oracle knows that `temp` is key-preserved in the view you are updating, which is what makes the above syntax OK.

One other caveat: I once encountered a situation where the rows from the `SELECT` view were not in the same order as the table.  The result was that performance *tanked*, as the update had to revisit each block several times.  An `ORDER BY temp.rowid` in the `SELECT` view would fix that.

Comment: If temp gets a natural key which doesn't exist in its dimension, then the insert will fail because of the FK - rather than the matching ID being set to -1 by the update/merge. I'd assumed the left joins were for that scenario, but of course they may just be for null keys, which would be fine. (I don't think you have to have the FKs for this to be key-preserved, but it'll perform much better if they're there, and indexed).

Comment: I'd just assumed the `LEFT JOIN`s were for `NULL` keys.  If unknown natural keys are a real possibility, then you're right -- the foreign keys aren't necessary.  The `UNIQUE` constraints on the natural key columns in the dimension tables will be enough to keep `temp` key-preserved.  I'll clarify my answer on that point.  Thanks for the comment.